# Image cache with Ionic 4 Capacitor: capacitor-image-cache plugin

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I want to use capacitor-image-cache plugin with my Ionic 4 application.

To install I run:

`npm i capacitor-image-cache st-cached-image`

When I launch the page where I import :

`import 'st-cached-image/dist/cached-image';`

The console displays this error, see this capture:

[image]

I have removed the plugin and re-install it, same error. What can I do ?